# dynamically allocating 3d array

Tags: c++, dynamic, multidimensional-array

I'm a little confused about dynamically allocating a 3d array. Right now, I'm just allocating one big block of memory like so:

```
int height = 10;
int depth = 20;
int width = 5;

int* arr;
arr = new int[height * width * depth];
```

Now I'd like to change a value in the 3D array, say:

```
//arr[depth][width][height]
arr[6][3][7] = 4;
```

However, I can't use the above code to change the value. How can I use a single index to access the element at position depth = 6, width = 3, height = 7?

```
arr[?] = 4;
```

Is there a better way to dynamically allocate a 3D array?

Comment: It's the pointer I think, if you need 3 dimensions then shouldn't it be int ***arr = new int[height][width][depth]; ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To index into the flat 3-dimensional array:

```
arr[x + width * (y + depth * z)]
```

Where x, y and z correspond to the first, second and third dimensions respectively and width and depth are the width and depth of the array.

This is a simplification of `x + y * WIDTH + z * WIDTH * DEPTH`.

Comment: Sorry, so x corresponds to the width element, y to the height element and z to the depth element or do I have that wrong? So to get the element with depth = 6, width = 3, height = 7: arr[3 + 5 * (7 + 20 * 6)] = arr[638]?

Comment: @user974967: `x is the height`, `y is the width` and `z is the depth`. To access `arr[6][3][7]` use `arr[6 + 5 * (3 + 20 * 7)]`. Basically, height, width, then depth in that order.

Answer (score 15):

C inclined way of doing this is:

```
int ***arr = new int**[X];
for (i = 0; i < z_size; ++i) {
  arr[i] = new int*[Y];
  for (j = 0; j < WIDTH; ++j)
    arr[i][j] = new int[Z];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To have a simple indexing mechanism like arr[height][width][depth], and to also have default values in the allocated memory to be initialized to 0, please try the following:

```
// Dynamically allocate a 3D array
/*  Note the parenthesis at end of new. These cause the allocated memory's
    value to be set to zero a la calloc (value-initialize). */
    arr = new int **[height]();
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new int *[width]();
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
            arr[i][j] = new int [depth]();
    }
```

And here's the corresponding deallocation:

```
//Dynamically deallocate a 3D array

for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        delete[] arr[i][j];
    delete[] arr[i];
}
delete[] arr;
```

Answer (score 5):

Allocation and deallocation for a 3D array (in heap) are exactly the opposite to each other. The key thing to remember, while deallocating the memory properly, is to use the `delete` keywords as many times as the `new` keyword has been used.
Here's my code for initialization and clean up of a 3D array:

```
int ***ptr3D=NULL;
ptr3D=new int**[5];

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    ptr3D[i] = new int*[5];  

    for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        ptr3D[i][j]=new int[5]; 

        for(int k=0;k<5;k++)
        {
            ptr3D[i][j][k]=i+j+k; 
        }
    }
}
//Initialization ends here
...
... //Allocation of values

cout << endl <<"Clean up starts here " << endl;

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        delete[] ptr3D[i][j];   
    }
    delete[] ptr3D[i];
}
delete ptr3D;
```

Notice that for 3 `new` keywords, 3 corresponding `delete` keywords have been used.
This should clean up all the memory allocated to the 3D array in heap and Valgrind can be used to verify it in each stage.