# Invalid write of size of when declaring std::pair

Tags: c++

I came across a memory problem when I declare a variable:

```
std::pair<int, int> best_cost[n][m][DIR];
```

In this case, n and m are both const int 1066 and DIR is 8. By running Valgrind I get an error:

```
Invalid write of size 8
==73213==    at 0x15D3B75E: simple_planner::SimplePlanner::aStar(geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > const&, geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > const&, std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > > >&) (in /home/yyu/devel/lib/libsimple_planner.so)
==73213==  Address 0xfe0f340 is on thread 8's stack
```

Am I declaring the variable wrong?

My end use of this variable is to get the direction on a specific coordinate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going by your numbers, `best_cost` is `(4+4)*1066*1066*8` = 72 MB. This is well above the default stack size limit for most platforms. Moving this allocation to the heap or the static section should allow you to safely use it.

Comment: And how exactly can I move it to heap or static section ? :)

Comment: [Which would lead to a read/write error ... also known as ... a stack overflow :)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Very_large_stack_variables)

Comment: Either move the definition of `best_cost` to the top level (static section) or use the `new` operator to create your structure (heap). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238699/dynamically-allocating-3d-array) for more information.

Comment: Cheers guys. That is really a good lesson for me. I never thought about these memory problems before (came from Python lol).

Comment: BTW,  on linux the default stack size is 10 MB on windows it is 1 MB.

Comment: @Botje: No `new` please, `std::vector<..>` or `std::unique_ptr<std::array<..>>` instead.

Comment: @Jarod42 Fair enough. Step one was switching to a heap allocation, changing the data structure to something other than a three-dimensional static array was step two ;)

Comment: Both `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>>>` or  `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>` are fine for me. `new T` or `new T[N]` is not.